# how can I increase response window size of cassendra datastax dev centre from 300 to 1000

Tags: cassandra, datastax

[Screenshot of DataStax DevCenter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GQLB.png)

How can I increase response window size (highlighted in image) from 300 to 1000 in DataStax DevCenter?

Comment: where is the image? can you please state more context about the problem, what have you done to resolve it ?

Answer (score 1):

Notice at the very top of your image, it says "with limit" followed by a text box containing the number "300."  Try increasing that to 1000.

Also, how many `glusr_id`s are you specifying with your IN clause?  Judging by the size of the window, it looks like a lot.  Multi-key queries are considered to be anti-patterns, because of all the extra network traffic they create.  That might be why it's taking 3384ms to return just 300 rows.